# Как достать URL?

Tags: java, split

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно из данной абракадабры:

```
<img src="https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22e/_v5QVn3WAVk.jpg" class="ph_img" data-id="-52952419_345698085" data-src_big="https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22f/JRueLkVn0SY.jpg|604|604">
```

достать эту ссылку:

```
https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22f/JRueLkVn0SY.jpg
```

Я хотел воспользоваться методом `replace ('"', ' ');`, а затем воспользоваться методом `split()` и создать массив и в конце просто взять нужный мне элемент массива.

Проблема в том, что я не могу скомпилировать абракадабру из-за вездесущих кавычек.

Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый примитивный способ основан на методах `substring(...)` и `indexOf(...)` класса `String`:

```
String s = "<img src=\"https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22e/_v5QVn3WAVk.jpg\" class=\"ph_img\" data-id=\"-52952419_345698085\" data-src_big=\"https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22f/JRueLkVn0SY.jpg|604|604\">";
String link = s.substring(s.indexOf("data-src_big=\"")+14, s.indexOf("|"));
```

> Проблема в том, что я не могу скомпилировать абракадабру из-за вездесущих кавычек

Кавычки нужно экранировать бэкслешем:

```
\"
```

**UPD**. С помощью `jsoup` Вашу задачу можно решить, например, так:

```
Document page = Jsoup.parse("<img src=\"https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22e/_v5QVn3WAVk.jpg\" class=\"ph_img\" data-id=\"-52952419_345698085\" data-src_big=\"https://pp.vk.me/c618831/v618831071/1c22f/JRueLkVn0SY.jpg|604|604\">");
String link = page.select("img").get(0).attr("data-src_big").split(Pattern.quote("|"))[0];
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Абракадабру я получил с помощью парсинга страницы. Я не смогу вручную расставить слеши. Можно ли как-то сделать это программно.

Comment: @KojerDefor, Экранировать спецсимволы нужно как раз только в том случае, если они записываются вручную, в других случаях экранирование не нужно. И еще, если Вы парсите `HTML` с помощью чего-нибудь типа `jsoup`, то искомую ссылку можно получить проще.

Comment: Да, наверное можно. Буду продолжать разбираться с `jsoup`. Спасибо.